# How to make flexible width 2d FlatList in react-native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I am using react native 0.57. I want to make 2D Grid for non-fixed width and fixed height boxes by using Flatlist. Something like grid show be free to adjust the number of columns according to the screen size. I am unable to implement it.

I can use fixed column but I want my grid to ajust per the device width. The box width can be unpredictable depending upon the text between them. Thanks in advance

Example: In gmail:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex property , and a width of null.

assuming you have a renderitem function and a max of 4 columns, you will need to have some "dummy items" in your flatlist data

```
<FlatList
          style={{flex:1}}
          data={[1,2,3,4,dummy,dummy,3,4,1,2,dummy,dummy]}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          numColumns={4} 
        />

    renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
      if(item==='dummy'){return <View/>}
        return (
          <View style={{height:100,width:null,flex:1,backgroundcolor:'red'}}/>
        );
      };
```

use flex 1 to fill "dummy" space or flex 1/2 to fill half of the screen , etc.

Comment: I don't want to specify the columns pre-defined. I just want that according the width of the box, it automatically flex-wrap

Comment: As per your answer, it will force them to 4 column or n columns. Instead I need something like masonry (only height are fixed for each element but the width may be differ for each element)

Comment: Oh dear, you are in for a ride, a really good ride , there is already some libraries like https://github.com/idibidiart/react-native-responsive-grid .

Comment: No man, I think you misunderstood the problem. I have boxes having some name (text) in them. I want to show them one after the another in a row until that row is not filled. after that row is filled come to 2nd line. But try to put as many name in a row as you can. Height is fixed but width will depend upon the text. 


Example:
| Name1| | long name so it will cover more space | | small |